# Next.js basepath not taking effect

Tags: next.js, base-path

I'm not able to use a basepath in my Next.js project, despite having searched the docs, blogs, and forums for an hour.

Me trying to use an absolute path:

[image]

I followed the docs and set up my `next.config.js` looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  basePath: "/src",
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [`baseUrl`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/absolute-imports-and-module-aliases) instead.